# get pod creation status from k8s api json using jq

Tags: jq, kubernetes-apiserver

I am trying to use jq in the following to get a status on my pod "my pod":

```
curl '127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/pods' | jq -r '.items[] | select(.metadata.name)'
```

This give me a ton of json, more specific how do you read json from k8s api - to get the status of a pod - running or not?

If I get items within a pod:

```
 curl '127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/pods' | jq -r 'select(.items[].metadata.name="go-test-volume1").items[]
```

Sure enough I get a list, but which one to chose - there is a status.phase in all of them?

[image: items]

In the case of a status of CrashLoopBackOff:

```
 curl '127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/pods' |
  jq -r '.items[] | select(.metadata.name == "my-pod").status.phase'
```

Will show it as Running?

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: Please be more specific. What does the JSON look like? What information do you want from it?

Comment: Thanks, yes select(.metadata.name == "my-pod-name") is in the right direction. I guess the items within the pod ".items[]" there is containers. I am looking for the pod status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need :

```
curl '127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/pods' |
  jq -r '.items[] | select(.metadata.name == "my-pod").status.phase'
```

Comment: items in a pod?

Comment: But you are right select(.metadata.name... will give me the item within the pod.... hmmm, I will accept you answer, thanks!

Comment: And items[0] within the pod is the same as: 'select(.items[].metadata.name="my-pod").items[0].metadata.name'

Comment: Sorry, I will un-accept as I just found that if you have a status of CrashLoopBackOff, curl '127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/pods' |
  jq -r '.items[] | select(.metadata.name == "my-pod").status.phase' will show it as Running

Comment: In your original post, you were asking about the status of a pod, not of individual containers.

Comment: Right, I will accept - thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the right status:

```
curl '127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/pods' |
  jq -r '.items[] | select(.metadata.name == "my-pod).status.containerStatuses[0].state'
```